# Closing a slidedown on click

Tags: javascript, navigation, slidedown

Demonstrating almost total ignorance but here goes:

I've got a simple function using slideDown to show a hidden ul when you hover over a parent li.  It works great.  But I need the ul to hide itself again, when a nav item is clicked. Right now you have to move the mouse out of the area, which is fine in a browser, but a pain on touch.

Here's what I've got presently:

```
 $('#nav ul li').hover(
    function () {
        //show its submenu
        $('ul', this).slideDown(150);
    }, 
    function () {
        //hide its submenu
        $('ul', this).slideUp(150);         
    }

);
```

Here's my guess to add the click-to-close bit:

```
$('#nav ul li').click(

    function () {
        //hide its submenu
        $('ul', this).slideUp(150);         
    }

);
```

I'm not so good at guessing. A point in the right direction would make my night.

Comment: can you upload your code to jsfiddle? but from looking at your code, first i'll put .stop() before each slide.  $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(150);

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EJ5qM/ is it. But, of course, it works there -- so something else must be going on.  Would there be a better way to do it, maybe, that might solve whatever the mystery issue is?